# IntelliJ, Unable to edit JSP files

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 12.0.4 Community Edition.

My problem is that I can only Open the JSP Files and just type something in them. Backspace, DELETE and other editing Keys don't work and the whole IDE hangs somehow and I must restart the IntelliJ.

the Logfiles contain dosen of such entry:

```
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4  Build #IC-123.169 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - JDK: 1.7.0_09 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - OS: Windows 7 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - Last Action: EditorEnter 
  2013-05-07 10:50:25,028 [  36991]  ERROR - .psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread - View provider com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider@1558433 refused to parse text with Language: TEXT; base: Language: ANY; copy: Language: ANY; fileType: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.AbstractFileType@1573ede 
  java.lang.RuntimeException: View provider com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider@1558433 refused to parse text with Language: TEXT; base: Language: ANY; copy: Language: ANY; fileType: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.AbstractFileType@1573ede
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.text.BlockSupportImpl.makeFullParse(BlockSupportImpl.java:193)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.text.BlockSupportImpl.reparseRangeInternal(BlockSupportImpl.java:143)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.text.BlockSupportImpl.reparseRange(BlockSupportImpl.java:82)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.doCommit(DocumentCommitThread.java:578)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.access$600(DocumentCommitThread.java:67)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread$3.run(DocumentCommitThread.java:460)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1155)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.commitUnderProgress(DocumentCommitThread.java:473)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.access$500(DocumentCommitThread.java:67)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread$2.run(DocumentCommitThread.java:352)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.pollQueue(DocumentCommitThread.java:349)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.run(DocumentCommitThread.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

has somebody the same Problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but you could try to [Invalidate the caches](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have the same problem. Minimizing and reopening easily done by pressing `ALT + TAB` `ALT + TAB` (you have to lift the `ALT` key too) solves this problem.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried both suggestions, but none of them has worked.